# jquery animate slide left open hidden

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to make the slider left panel be hidden then then when clicked revealed not as it is revealed and then when clicked hidden can someone please help

this is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slideleft .button').click(function() {
    var $lefty = $(this).next();
    $lefty.animate({
      left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
        -$lefty.outerWidth() :
        0
    });
  });
});
```

and this is what im using

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Cheers

Comment: Can you post this on jsfiddle? If not include HTML and CSS in the question.

Comment: What happens when you click the button? Does it do anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
#slideleft .inner { 
  left:-350px; 
}
```